# Scroll then fix to top header in html

Tags: javascript, html

So, i'd like to have an header working similarly to the one here http://www.blackmesasource.com/ , the only problem being I know nothing about javascript and jquery, can anyone help me?

Comment: maybe you should use a wordpress theme or something, otherwise you will have to learn some javascript or read documentation. your example uses a combination of http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/ and https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider

Comment: Hey, what you want to achive is persitant header. You have a very good exemple here : https://css-tricks.com/persistent-headers/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice - I just knocked this up for you - it's rough and has had no cross-browser testing:

```
<style type="text/css">

    body {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }

    #hero {
        background-color:#eee;
    }

    nav {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        background-color:#ccc;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        width:100%;
        padding:20px;
    }

    nav.fixed-position {
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        bottom:initial;
    }

</style>

<body>

    <div>

        <div id="hero">

            <nav id="nav-menu">
                Your nav here
            </nav>

        </div>

        <section style="height:2000px;">

            content

        </section>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var hero = document.getElementById('hero'),
            nav = document.getElementById("nav-menu"),
            viewportHeight = Math.max(window.innerHeight || 0),
            navOffsetTop = nav.offsetTop;

        hero.style.height = viewportHeight + 'px';

        var hasScrolled = function() {

            var fromTop = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop || 0;

            if (navOffsetTop < fromTop) {
                nav.classList.add('fixed-position');
            } else {
                nav.classList.remove('fixed-position');
            }

        }

        window.addEventListener('scroll', hasScrolled);

    </script>

</body>
```

You can drop this into an empty file and run it in your browser to see the result - I tested it in Firefox with no problems but as I say, it will need additional work; such as:

- Crossbrowser - depending on what level of IE support you plan to have, classList might not work.
- Optimisation - currently the hasScrolled function fires every time the user scrolls, you might want to find a way to limit that.
- Global vars - I've made no attempt to use a nice clean namespace for the JS, something else you might like to look into.

Additionally, this doesn't require jQuery, but given what I've just suggested you need to do you might want to look into using it - it's mainly crossbrowser which will help you out alot if you don't really know JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can see best resources here. Just follow same structure https://css-tricks.com/scroll-fix-content/